# PyQt5 QML Debugging enabled, qmljsdebugger option doesn't do anything

Tags: python, debugging, qml, pyqt5

I've built PyQt5 5.10.1 against Qt 5.5 with the `--qml-debug` flag.

When I import QtQml I get the message "QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment."

but whenever I try to run my application, passing arguments to the QApplication constructor, there's no indication that running my app with the `-qmljsdebugger=port:1234,block` option does anything. I'm expecting a message like "`QML Debugger: Waiting for connection on port 1234`", or "`QML Debugger: Ignoring "qmljsdebugger=port:1234". Debugging has not been enabled.`", but neither of these messages are displayed.

I've tried printing `QApplication.arguments()`, and the qmljsdebugger argument is not there, but the name of the program is.

I've tried passing `['program.py', '-qmljsdebugger=port:1234,block']` directly to the `QApplication()` constructor, but the second argument is not visible from the call to `QApplication.arguments()`. Funny enough if i remove the leading '-' from the argument, it shows up in that list but doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debugging was not being turned on because i was using QQmlEngine instead of QQmlApplicationEngine.